# Is it possible to become a policeman in Germany as a non-citizen?

Tags: germany, eu-citizens

Are non-citizens allowed to become police officers in Germany? Are there any restrictions? Are there any advantages for EU-citizens?

Comment: You will most likely have to prove your language competence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This highly depends on your *Bundesland* since the police is under the jurisdiction of a federal state. Some of them explicitly welcome people without citizenship to apply, others do not permit them at all. You will however be required to deliver a *Führungszeugnis*, a certificate of good conduct, when applying which might be problematic depending on whether your former country of residence offers such a certificate that matches the German requirements.

For example, the [federal state of *Hessen*](http://www.polizei.hessen.de/icc/internetzentral/nav/cf4/cf470ee1-825a-f6f8-6373-a91bbcb63046.htm) welcomes foreigners' applications. The federal state of Bayern welcomes applications after assessing the [applicant's language competence](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polizeiausbildung_in_Bayern) where bilingual applicants are given an edge. However, foreign applicant's are still considered only outside of the default application process where for example [Turkish citizens are most commonly accepted](http://dtj-online.de/zukunftsberuf-auch-fur-migranten-wie-werde-ich-polizist-1789). In principle, I believe it is possible to become a policeman in every federal state as long as you are a qualified applicant, especially for the *gehobener Dienst* (higher service).

Answer (score 5):

Under EU law, some positions might be restricted but it's difficult to imagine that the entire police service could be. Not only that but if a position is not deemed to be restricted to German nationals, then I think that EU citizens must be treated equally (i.e. there can be no priority to German citizens or anything like that).

That said, in Germany police is a provincial matters, so the rules [differ from *Land* to *Land*](http://www.polizei-einstellung.de/bewerbung-als-nichtdeutscher-oder-als-eu-burger-bei-der-polizei/2011/12/07/). As you will see, other EU citizens can generally apply on a par with German citizens but it is even possible in some places for non-EU citizens, sometimes with a special authorization. One restriction is that you probably need to speak German.