# Can a non-German become a police officer in Berlin?

Tags: germany, us-citizens, residency, working

I saw a previous question here about how it's possible for a non-citizen to become an officer in a few different German states, and Berlin mentions:

"Nur Deutsche im Sinne des Artikel 116 des Grundgesetzes der Bundesrepublik Deutschland oder Staatsangehöriger eines Mitgliedslandes der Europäischen Union. **Für Angehörige anderer Nationalitäten gelten Sonderregelungen.**
" 
I was wondering if anyone knew or could figure out what nations this was referring to; I'm a US citizen.

Previous Expats question: [Is it possible to become a policeman in Germany as a non-citizen?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/456/16307)

The website that specifically states this: [Landespolizei-Bundespolizei-Einstellungstest](http://www.polizei-einstellung.de/bewerbung-als-nichtdeutscher-oder-als-eu-burger-bei-der-polizei/2011/12/07/)

Comment: *I saw a previous thread* Reference please!

Comment: Feeding the quoted text into Google translate yields "Only Germans within the meaning of Article 116 of the Basic Law of the Federal Republic of Germany or a national of a member state of the European Union. Special rules apply to nationals of other nationalities"  (and that agrees with my German).

Comment: *very* similar text is also found on https://www.berlin.de/polizei/beruf/polizist-polizistin-werden/bewerbung-einstellung/, except there it ends "*Für Angehörige anderer Nationalitäten gelten Sonderregelungen – bei Bedarf bitte erfragen*", and the last bit is "if necessary, please ask".  I think you need to ask the Berlin police (and come back here and post the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Mainly first generation immigrants, such as turks or other nationalities where the renouncing of there citizenship causes problems.

This statement is based on public statements incouraging applications from these groups including those that may have dual citizenship problems.

Official Police recruitment sites only meantion that it is possible and that you can contact them for further information.